# How to compute this path integral?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, feynman-integral, path-integral

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be phase space with coordinates $(p,q)$ and let $\epsilon>0\,.$ Then given any path $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and any large enough $N>0\,,$ we can approximate $\gamma$ by a piecewise linear function obtained by connecting $N+1$ points $(p_0,q_0),\ldots,(p_N,q_N)$ in the image of $\gamma$ with line segments, such that that $$|p_n-p_{n-1}|<\epsilon, |q_n-q_{n-1}|<\epsilon\,,\; 1\le n\le N\,.$$ Denot all points $(p_0,q_0,\ldots,p_N,q_N)\in \mathbb{R}^{2(N+1)}$ satisfying these inequalities by $\Omega_{N,\epsilon}\,.$ From now on we will fix the endpoints of $\gamma$ and denote them by $(p_0,q_0),(p_N,q_N)\,,$ respectively.

I want to compute

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\lim_{N\to +\infty} \int_{\Omega_{N,\epsilon}} \left\{\prod_{n=1}^{N-1} \mathrm{d}q_n\right\} \left\{\prod_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{\mathrm{d}p_n}{2\pi\hslash}\right\} 
\exp\left[{\frac{i}{\hslash}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(p_n+p_{n-1}) (q_n - q_{n-1})}{2}} \right]\,,\tag{1}
$$

and I suspect that one can replace $(p_n+p_{n-1}) (q_n - q_{n-1})/2$ by $p_{n-1} (q_n - q_{n-1})\,.$

I have a guess that, if this converges, then it is equal to (up to a multiplicative constant) $$
e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{(p_N+p_0)(q_N-q_0)}{2}}\,.
$$
However, I'm not sure how to show this and I haven't been able to get Mathematica to help.
$$ $$
For some additional information, one can interpret $\frac{(p_N+p_0)(q_N-q_0)}{2}$ as $\int_{\gamma}p\,dq\,,$ where $\gamma$ is the line segment connecting $(p_0,q_0)$ to $(p_N,q_N)\,.$

Formally, this limit of finite dimensional integrals is $$
\int_{(p_0,q_0)}^{(p_N,q_N)}\mathcal{D}p\mathcal{D}q\,e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{\gamma} p\,dq}
$$

The guess $e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{(p_N+p_0)(q_N-q_0)}{2}}$ is consistent with the fact that, when we integrate the above integral over $p_N$ we should get $\delta(q_N-q_0)$ — the reason for this is that when we compute the usual phase space path integral from quantum mechanics with the Hamiltonian being equal to $0$ (so that there is no time evolution), the result is just $\langle q_N|q_0\rangle\,.$

Comment: According to Eq. 2.18 of H. Kleinert, Path Integrals the answer is $\delta(q_N-q_0)$, so your intuition is correct. You can see the derivation there.

Comment: @yarchik Yes that’s right, but it still doesn’t tell me what my original integral is, but it does pass that one sanity check.